Power BI DAX: Ranking Works at Total Level but Not When Drilling Down into Categories
I'm working on a DAX query in Power BI to create a table that summarizes sales data and ranks items based on their sales. The ranking works perfectly at the total level, but when I drill down into a specific category, the ranking does not adjust according to the subcategory data and still reflects the overall total ranking.
Here is my DAX code:
tbl3 = 
SUMMARIZE(
    f_sale_agg_month,
    d_item[division_id],
    d_item[division_description],  
    d_item[main_category_description],
    d_item[category_description],
    d_date[year],  
    d_date[year_month],
    "fsg_test", SUM(f_sale_agg_month[store_sale_cents]) / 100  
)

Rank = 
RANKX(
    'tbl3',  
    [fsg_test],
    ,
    DESC,
    Skip)

group = SWITCH(
TRUE(),
[Rank] >= 1 && [Rank] <= 20, "1-20 biggest items",
[Rank] >= 21 && [Rank] <= 50, "21-50 biggest items",
[Rank] >= 51 && [Rank] <= 100, "51-100 biggest items",
[Rank] >= 101 && [Rank] <= 200, "101-200 biggest items",
[Rank] >= 201 && [Rank] <= 500, "201-500 biggest items",
[Rank] > 500, ">500"
)

The problem:

The ranking works correctly when viewing the data at the total level, but as soon as I drill down into a "main category," the ranking does not adjust according to the data within that category. It seems like the ranking still considers the total sales rather than the sales within the drilled-down category.

Question:

How can I modify my DAX code so that the ranking adjusts based on the context of the drilled-down categories? I'm looking for a solution that ensures the ranking is dynamically updated depending on the selected category level in the report.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I would like the structure to be as follows:


Can you please provide some sample data, expected output, or a file so we may replicate this issue?

Unfortunately, I am unable to provide you with the dataset. However, I added a picture how I like the structure to be.

I recreated your issue using mock data. In the below matrix, I was able to rank both the division_description and the drilled into main_category column.

First you will need to sum the sales using this measure:
Sum of Sales = SUM(tbl3[fsg_test])

Then create this Ranking measure:
Rank = 
VAR rankDivision = RANKX(ALLSELECTED( tbl3[division_description]), [Sum of Sales],, DESC, Dense)
VAR rankCategory = RANKX(ALLSELECTED( tbl3[main_category_description]), [Sum of Sales],, DESC, Dense)

RETURN SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        ISINSCOPE(tbl3[main_category_description]), rankCategory,
        ISINSCOPE(tbl3[division_description]), rankDivision
        )

Input Data for tbl3:



division_id
division_description
main_category_description
category_description
year
year_month
fsg_test




101
Electronics
Audio
Headphones
2023
07/01/2023
10000.5


101
Electronics
Visual
Televisions
2023
08/01/2023
15000.75


101
Electronics
Visual
Televisions
2023
08/01/2023
10


102
Clothing
Men
Shirts
2023
07/01/2023
20000.2


102
Clothing
Women
Dresses
2023
08/01/2023
25000.4


103
Grocery
Fruits
Apples
2024
01/01/2024
30000.6


103
Grocery
Vegetables
Carrots
2024
02/01/2024
35000.8




Thank you so much for your help and the great example data. I tested the code with your sample data, and the measures worked perfectly—well done!
However, I’m struggling with grouping based on rank sizes like 1-20, 21-50, etc. When rank is a column, grouping only works at the top level. But when rank is a measure, the grouping doesn’t work at all.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions? I’d greatly appreciate any advice!
Thanks again for your support

group = SWITCH(
TRUE(),
[Rank] >= 1 && [Rank] <= 20, "1-20 largest items",
[Rank] >= 21 && [Rank] <= 50, "21-50 largest items",
[Rank] >= 51 && [Rank] <= 100, "51-100 largest items",
[Rank] >= 101 && [Rank] <= 200, "101-200 largest items",
[Rank] >= 201 && [Rank] <= 500, "201-500 largest items",
[Rank] > 500, ">500"
)

Where are you putting the group measure in your visual? I put it in the values of the matrix and it worked perfectly.

I want to place the "group" measure in the rows of the matrix table, but it's not working for me. When I place it in the values section, it works. I added a few more rows to the table you created, bringing it to around 1000 rows to test the grouping, and it does group correctly when it's placed as a value. If you look at the image in my post, you can see the structure I'm aiming for in my table.
